# FtpGetFile WinINEt never returns

Tags: c++, ftp, freeze, wininet

I'm experiencing a curious problem (very strange, let me say hehe). During a FTP download of an EXE file (24 MB), if the connection is ever interrupted, it appears that the function FtpGetFile of the WinINEt library has a bug and it never returns. This causes that future file transfers fail (the connection is already opened).
Apparently, I found a workaround by increasing the timeout of the server transfers but I do not like it. I didn't found a similar problem by googling (maybe I introduced the wrong keywords).

I read some forums on the internet and it seems that everyone does not recommend using the FtpGetFile because it is buggy.

This appears in a network scenario that has a big lag (and not always) but in good conditions it disappears (downloads take place correctly and FtpGetFile returns always).

Here is how I use the function:

`if( FtpGetFile(m_hFtpSession, strSourcePath.c_str(), strTargetPath.c_str(), 0, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0)==TRUE)`

Can anyone confirm that? Should I refactor my code and look for an update?

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain me the -1????? Is this trolling?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to download files without using FtpGetFile. I hope this code can help someone:

```
bool RetrieveFile(const string& strSource, const string& strTarget) {

   /* The handle for the transfer */
   HINTERNET hTransfer = NULL;

   /*
    * Set default error
    */
   DWORD error = ERROR_SUCCESS;

   if( !isConnected ) {
     debug("%s(): ERROR not connected\n", __FUNCTION__);
     return false;
   }

   /* Initiate access to a remote FTP connection */
   hTransfer = FtpOpenFile(hFtpSession, strSource.c_str(), GENERIC_READ,
       FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);

   if(hTransfer) {
      std::ofstream myostream(strTarget.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
      if ( myostream.is_open() ) {
         static const DWORD SIZE = 1024;

         BYTE data[SIZE];
         DWORD size = 0;
         do {
            BOOL result = InternetReadFile(hTransfer, data, SIZE, &size);
            if ( result == FALSE ) {
               error = GetLastError();
               Debug("InternetReadFile(): %lu\n", error);
            }
            myostream.write((const char*)data, size);
         }
         while ((error == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (size > 0));

         // Close the stream
         myostream.close();
      }
      else {
         Debug("Could not open '%s'.\n", strTarget.c_str());
         error = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND; // Not necessarily not found, but it is to describe a file error which is different from ERROR_SUCCESS
      }

      // Close
      const BOOL result = InternetCloseHandle(hTransfer);
      if ( result == FALSE ) {
         const DWORD error = GetLastError();
         debug("InternetClose(): %lu\n", error);
      }

      /* Check error status of the process */
      return (error == ERROR_SUCCESS);
   }

   DWORD dwInetError;
   DWORD dwExtLength = 1000;
   TCHAR *szExtErrMsg = NULL;
   TCHAR errmsg[1000];
   szExtErrMsg = errmsg;
   int returned = InternetGetLastResponseInfo( &dwInetError, szExtErrMsg, &dwExtLength );
   debug("dwInetError: %d  Returned: %d\n", dwInetError, returned);
   debug("Buffer: %s\n", szExtErrMsg);

   debug("%s() : ERROR to get '%s' file (errorCode=%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, strSource.c_str(), GetLastError());

   return false;
}
```